# Get largest mail items in Exchange 2007

Tags: powershell, exchange-server

I haven't had much like in finding a solution to this (other than installing EWS on the server which isn't a viable option yet as the Exchange server is hosted).

I essentially need to parse the Exchange database, and each individual mailbox, for items larger than 25MB in size, then spit this out into a CSV with the Mailbox and location of that item. However, as far as I can see, there doesn't seem to be any cmdlet in Powershell that can achieve.

Any ideas?

Comment: If by "install EWS" you mean the EWS Managed API, you don't install that on the server.  You install it on the client machine you're connecting to the server with.

Answer (score 0):

There are some powershell examples in this link that may help - [use-powershell-to-data-mine-your-outlook-inbox](http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2011/05/26/use-powershell-to-data-mine-your-outlook-inbox.aspx).

It loads `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook` assembly into the powershell session to hook into Outlook